# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (cors) ajax request not working on mobile device

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app by using jQuery mobile and phonegap. Below are the versions of my phonegap, phonegap-1.1.0.js, jquery-1.7.1.js, jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js, From developing app I am calling Ajax request of other host having PHP website.

On that server I have set 
    `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
and in Js file defined
    `$.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;`

I am testing this app by using chrome browser on local system, Where everything is working correctly and I am getting responce. But when I generate build by using https://build.phonegap.com for android and ios. The cors Ajax request are not working

Below is the ajax code which I am calling

```
 $.ajax({
    type       : "POST",
    url        : // Other server url
    data       : {
        fId:'42'
    },
    dataType   : 'json',
    success    : function(response) {

    },
    error      : function(response) {
            // Response is coming in this case                 
    }
});`
```

Can anybody tell which settings I need to set

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide